# How can you learn to engage in highly focused thinking for a sustained period of time?

Tags: attention

Is there some research on how to engage in highly-focused thinking for more than a few hours at a time?

I have read (informally, i.e., not research papers) that engaging in enjoyable non-focused thinking for a few hours after the effort may help one recharge. Is this true, can anyone please refer me to any research done in this area (hopefully including physiological aspects)?